# Convert Json to CSV and download file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, csv

I have an url that returns json object.

I need to have an button with onClick function that will call that API, get the json object, convert it to CSV and allow user to download it on thier local machine.

The CSV file should have structure as follows:

```
"Header 1","Header 2","Header 3","Header 4","Header 5","Header 6","Header 7","Header 8","Header 9","Header 10","Header 11","Header 12"
"B-E7BE5602-2F9B-E3","11608501","Active","2023-06-29","1","0","1","ID","OPEN","Yes","Yes","FLOWER"
"B-480A8929-57D5-97","11608502","Active","2023-06-29","1","0","1","ID","OPEN","No","No","FLOWER"
```

this is the json I get from the API:

```
{
    "items": {
        "recordsFiltered": 2,
        "data": [{
                "numOfIds": 1,
                "productId": null,
                "askOrgId": "Yes",
                "orderId": 11608501,
                "orgSelectionType": "FLOWER",
                "batchCode": "B-E7BE5602-2F9B-E3",
                "IDType": "OPEN",
                "batchId": 413,
                "creationDate": "2022-06-29",
                "isOnline": "Yes",
                "productName": null,
                "batchProductArray": [{
                        "ID": 663255,
                        "TYPE": "PRODUCT",
                        "NAME": "SOME NAME"
                    }
                ],
                "numOfUsedIDs": 0,
                "redemptionMethod": "ID",
                "askSSN": "No",
                "askEmployeeId": "Yes",
                "batchStatus": "Active",
                "productType": null,
                "expirationDate": "2023-06-29"
            }, {
                "numOfIds": 1,
                "productId": null,
                "askOrgId": "No",
                "orderId": 11608502,
                "orgSelectionType": "LEAF",
                "batchCode": "B-480A8929-57D5-97",
                "IDType": "OPEN",
                "batchId": 414,
                "creationDate": "2022-06-29",
                "isOnline": "Yes",
                "productName": null,
                "batchProductArray": [{
                        "ID": 663255,
                        "TYPE": "PRODUCT",
                        "NAME": "Other Name"
                    }
                ],
                "numOfUsedIDs": 0,
                "redemptionMethod": "ID",
                "askSSN": "No",
                "askEmployeeId": "No",
                "batchStatus": "Active",
                "productType": null,
                "expirationDate": "2023-06-29"
            }, 
        ],
        "draw": 1,
        "recordsTotal": 2
    }
}
```

I tried below code but it gives me that my json is undefined

```
function downloadJSONAsCSV(endpoint) {
  // Fetch JSON data from the endpoint
  fetch(endpoint)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(jsonData => {
      // Convert JSON data to CSV
      let csvData = jsonToCsv(jsonData);

      // Create a CSV file and allow the user to download it
      let blob = new Blob([csvData], { type: 'text/csv' });
      let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      let a = document.createElement('a');
      a.href = url;
      a.download = 'data.csv';
      document.body.appendChild(a);
      a.click();
    })
    .catch(error => console.error(error));
}

function jsonToCsv(jsonData) {
  let csv = '';

  // Get the headers
  let headers = Object.keys(jsonData[0]);
  csv += headers.join(',') + '\n';

  // Add the data
  jsonData.forEach(function(row) {
    let data = headers.map(header => row[header]).join(',');
    csv += data + '\n';
  });

  return csv;
}
```

Plus I belive that the code above will not format the CSV file in the format I need.

Comment: In which line do you get the error?

Comment: let csvData = jsonToCsv(jsonData); brings me to .catch(error => console.error(error));
}

Comment: What do you see when you open the debugger with a breakpoint in `let csvData = jsonToCsv(jsonData);` and analyze `jsonData`? What is the actual valua? Does the given answer solve your problem?

Comment: Just a reminder, it's better to revoke the blob URL after `a.click();` to free some memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the problem with your code is that you try to convert the root node of the json data to csv instead of the data one, to fix this you just need to change `jsonToCsv(jsonData)` to `jsonToCsv(jsonData.items.data)`. Additionally you will need to add a `JSON.stringify` statement around for data mapping function. Iv'e made the necessary changes to your code and attached them below

```js
function downloadJSONAsCSV(endpoint) {
    // Fetch JSON data from the endpoint
    fetch(endpoint)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(jsonData => {
            // Convert JSON data to CSV
            let csvData = jsonToCsv(jsonData.items.data); // Add .items.data
            // Create a CSV file and allow the user to download it
            let blob = new Blob([csvData], { type: 'text/csv' });
            let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            let a = document.createElement('a');
            a.href = url;
            a.download = 'data.csv';
            document.body.appendChild(a);
            a.click();
        })
        .catch(error => console.error(error));
}
function jsonToCsv(jsonData) {
    let csv = '';
    // Get the headers
    let headers = Object.keys(jsonData[0]);
    csv += headers.join(',') + '\n';
    // Add the data
    jsonData.forEach(function (row) {
        let data = headers.map(header => JSON.stringify(row[header])).join(','); // Add JSON.stringify statement
        csv += data + '\n';
    });
    return csv;
}
```

Comment: it almost perfect but I need to set headers. Do you know how can I do that?

Comment: @Lenny Which headers?

Comment: "Header 1","Header 2","Header 3","Header 4","Header 5","Header 6","Header 7","Header 8","Header 9","Header 10","Header 11","Header 12"

Comment: In other words, can I change what parts of the json will be injected into the CSV and change thier order?

Comment: This looks like a different question. Please ask only one question per question and don't ask follow-up questions in comments. Create a new question for this. Your question actually doesn't even contain any question. "I need" isn't a question.